# How to include images inside joomla plugin's XML file?

Tags: xml, joomla

I did refer here: [Joomla plugin install xml -- install file to different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157771/joomla-plugin-install-xml-install-file-to-different-folder)

```
<media destination="com_helloworld">
    <filename>image.png</filename>
    <filename>flash.swf</filename>
</media>
```

What does this mean? `destination="com_helloworld"`I want images to be inside my plugin folder to be installed..How do I change my existing xml below? The `images` folder is in same directory as `js` and `cs`

```
 <files>
        <filename plugin="chat">chat.php</filename>
        <filename>js/jquery.js</filename>
        <filename>js/chat.js</filename>
        <filename>css/style.css</filename>
        <filename>index.html</filename>
    </files>
```

Doing this:

```
<media destination="com_helloworld">
        <filename>images/people.png</filename>
        <filename>images/sound.swf</filename>
    </media>
```

**Says: Unable to copy file from source...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Math5hias answer, you can use the `<media>` tag to install files into Joomla default media folder (which is `/media`).

If you add the `destination` attribute, an additional subfolder will be created, i.e. `/media/your_plugin_name`. If you are ok with putting your images in the `/media` root, you don't have to use this attribute.

If it's not working in your case, make sure images are included in your zip file, it sounds like it's not.

Finally, you can also create an **install script** to your plugin, to perform additional custom task, e.g. to copy / move files from `media` to `images`. Official Joomla documentation: https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Adding_an_install-uninstall-update_script_file

Comment: I fixed my answer as the correct media folder is `media`, not `images`.

Answer (score 1):

The destination info creates a new folder and add your files in there.

Try with file:

```
<files>
        <filename>image.jpg</filename>
        <filename>image.png</filename>
</files>
```

Comment: I think you mean `<media>` and not `<files>`.

Comment: my fault, so images should load with <media>?

Comment: You cannot install into `images` folder, only into `media` folder. That is a Joomla convention, all extensions assets should be within `media` folder.